# How do I align my navigation to the right without removing (display: inline;)?

Tags: html, css

How do I align my navbar to the right side without removing my `display: inline;`? 
If I remove my `display: inline;`, the `li` automatically aligns to the right side of the page but in a list format.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerContainer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #headerContainer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#headerContainer li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
#headerContainer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#headerContainer a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

I do not want to remove my `display: inline;` attribute because it's the attribute that aligns my list in one line, help please (might be a noob question lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out ( add `text-align: right;` to the `<ul>`):

**CSS**

```
#headerContainer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/rdsz2thp/6/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luis, it worked really well (although I remembered trying it in the (ul)..

Answer (score 0):

you need to set float:right for headerContainer.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerContainer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#headerContainer ul {
    float:right;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#headerContainer li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
#headerContainer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#headerContainer a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyawoG

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:right` to the ul (not the li's or your menu ordering will be reversed). This will allow you to include other elements in your header (logo?) but only your menu will float to the right.

```
#headerContainer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
#headerContainer li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
#headerContainer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#headerContainer a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1euq9r2s/)